# Shuffle data in a repeatable way (ability to get the same "random" order again)

Tags: sql, math, random, shuffle

This is the opposite of what most "random order" questions are about.
I want to select data from a database in random order. But I want to be able to repeat certain selects, getting the same order again.

#### Current (random) select:

```
SELECT custId, rand() as random from
(
    SELECT DISTINCT custId FROM dummy
)
```

Using this, every key/row gets a random number. Ordering those ascending results in a random order.

But I want to repeat this select, getting the very same order again. My idea is to calculate a random number (r) once per session (e.g. "4") and use this number to shuffle the data in some way.

#### My first idea:

```
SELECT custId, custId * 4 as random from
(
    SELECT DISTINCT custId FROM dummy
)
```

*(in real life "4" would be something like 4005226664240702)*

This results in a different number for each line but the same ones every run. By changing "r" to 5 all numbers will change.

The problem is: multiplication is not sufficient here. It just increases the numbers but keeps the order the same. Therefore I need some other kind of arithmetic function.

### More abstract

Starting with my data (A-D). *k* is the key and *r* is the random number currently used:

```
    k    r
A = 1    4
B = 2    4
C = 3    4
D = 4    4
```

Doing some calculation using *k* and *r* in every line I want to get something like:

```
    k    r
A = 1    4    --> 12
B = 2    4    --> 13
C = 3    4    --> 11
D = 4    4    --> 10
```

The numbers can be whatever they want, but when I order them ascending I want to get a different order than the initial one. In this case D, C, A, B, E.

Setting r to 7 should result in a different order (C, A, B, D):

```
    k    r
A = 1    7    --> 56
B = 2    7    --> 78
C = 3    7    --> 23
D = 4    7    --> 80
```

Every time I use r = 7 should result in the same numbers => same order.

**I'm looking for a mathematical function to do the calculation with k and r. Seeding the RAND() function is not suitable because it's not supported by some databases we support**

*Please note that r is already a randomly generated number*

---

#### Background

One Table - Two data consumers. One consumer will get random 5% of the table, the other one the other 95%. They don't just get the data but a generated SQL. So there are two SQL's which must not select the same data twice but still random.

Comment: What kind of server are you using?

Comment: The solution should be universal, without any special functions of certain servers. A pure mathematical solution would be just fine as well.

Comment: It seems a little contrived to brew your own random number generator when most implementations already have a working one.

Comment: r should be the result of a randomly generated number (using rand()). Mixing r and the static key k should still result in something random (or am I wrong here?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try and implement the Multiply-With-Carry PseudoRandomNumberGenerator. The C version goes like this (source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation)):

```c
m_w = <choose-initializer>;    /* must not be zero, nor 0x464fffff */
m_z = <choose-initializer>;    /* must not be zero, nor 0x9068ffff */

uint get_random()
{
    m_z = 36969 * (m_z & 65535) + (m_z >> 16);
    m_w = 18000 * (m_w & 65535) + (m_w >> 16);
    return (m_z << 16) + m_w;  /* 32-bit result */
}
```

In SQL, you could create a table Random, with two columns to contain `w` and `z`, and one `ID` column to identify each session. Perhaps your vendor supports variables and you need not bother with the table.

Nonetheless, even if we use a table, we immediately run into trouble cause ANSI SQL doesn't support unsigned INTs. In SQL Server I could switch to BIGINT, unsure if your vendor supports that.

```
CREATE TABLE Random (ID INT, [w] BIGINT, [z] BIGINT)
```

Initialize a new session, say number 3, by inserting 1 into z and the seed into w:

```
INSERT INTO Random (ID, w, z) VALUES (3, 8921, 1);
```

Then each time you wish to generate a new random number, do the computations:

```
UPDATE Random
SET
  z = (36969 * (z % 65536) + z / 65536) % 4294967296,
  w = (18000 * (w % 65536) + w / 65536) % 4294967296
WHERE ID = 3
```

(Note how I have replaced bitwise operands with div and mod operations and how, after computing, you need to mod 4294967296 to stay within the proper 32 bits unsigned int range.)

And select the new value:

```
SELECT(z * 65536 + w) % 4294967296
FROM Random
WHERE ID = 3
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bd8d5/5)

Comment: Wow, this is great. Your idea of using update every time you want to get a new random number is not that good for the performance when using this for huge amounts of data. But I already have an idea how this may work out just fine. Trying it out on monday. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this applies in non-SQL Server, but typically when you use a `RAND()` function, you can specify a seed. Everytime you specify the same seed, the randomization will be the same.

So, it sounds like you just need to store the seed number and use that each time to get the same set of random numbers.

[MSDN Article on RAND](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177610.aspx)

Comment: This way I would have to store a seed for every row. I could also store every key again (in the wished order) and read from that table right away. But I'm looking for a faster way (i'm talking about a lot of data)

Answer (score 0):

Each vendor has solved this in its own way. Creating your own implementation will be hard, since random number generation is difficult.

**Oracle**
dbms_random can be initialized with a seed: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_random.htm#i998255

**SQL Server**
First call to RAND() can provide a seed: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177610.aspx

**MySql**
First call to RAND() can provide a seed: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand

**Postgresql**
Use SET SEED or SELECT setseed() : http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/sql-set.html

Comment: I need a random number for every row. Seeding RAND() once will give me the same number every call:

From the SQL Server link:
`For one connection, if RAND() is called with a specified seed value, all subsequent calls of RAND() produce results based on the seeded RAND() call. For example, the following query will always return the same sequence of numbers.
SELECT RAND(100), RAND(), RAND()`


Same problem as @Derek Kromms solution. I would have to store the seed for every row. I'd rather store every key in the right order again and read them directly but it performs badly with lots of data.

Comment: That would make the Random function quite useless! If you set the seed once, all subsequent calls on the same connection will be the repeatable sequence seeded by the seed in the first call. So you need not store the seed for each row, just to call RAND in the same order

Comment: You and Derek are right! I've misunderstood it. The sequence just have to be the same. Apparently there are databases which do not support seeding of the rand() function. (Our product does support them, although I don't want to mention any names here).

Comment: A universal solution for databases with no seeding support would be just what I need. I'll wait and hope that somebody comes up with such a solution. If not I'll accept yours or Dereks answer...

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you name one database vendor that does not provide a seeded random implementation?

Comment: Sorry, NDA. They are still under development and don't have seeding functionality on their roadmap yet.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't call it generic, rather your-non-discloseable-vendor-specific, but I've added a somewhat ANSI-SQL compliant implementation as a different answer.

Comment: WARNING about relying on SEED() etc. for repeatability... Depending on the table and the session, the query might be executed in parallel.  This will destroy any repeatability (as I discovered after two days of debugging).  Solve it by removing the table/session/query's parallelism such as with a hint (and cross your fingers) or configuration.